# Help solving iPhone app crash

Tags: iphone, debugging, crash-reports

I released an update to one of my apps recently. This update made some small changes to the data structure, which is causing problems for some people. I have got a hold of some crash reports and narrowed it down to the line in question, but for the life of me can't see anything wrong with it. I'm not able to replicate the problem at my end either, which doesn't help.

The section of code is:

```
-(void)performV160Upgrade {
 for(id key in self.consumptionHistory) {
      Consumption* consumption = [self.consumptionHistory objectForKey:key];

      for(Entry* entry in consumption.entries) {
           if(!entry.emotionDescription || [entry.emotionDescription isEqualToString:@""]) {
                if(self.emotionDescriptionDefaults && [self.emotionDescriptionDefaults count] >= entry.emotion) {
                     entry.emotionDescription = [self.emotionDescriptionDefaults objectAtIndex:entry.emotion-1];
                }
           }
      }
 }

 NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"V160Upgrade"];
 [defaults synchronize];
 [self saveDataFile];
```

}

Specifically, the crash occurs on the innermost if statement, when assigning entry.emotionDescription (this is line 251). For some context, consumptionHistory is an NSMutableDictionary, consumption.entries is an NSMutableArray, self.emotionDescriptionDefaults is an NSMutableArray of NSString's, and entry.emotionDescription is an NSString.

I'll attach the crash log below. Any ideas or suggestions on where to go to from here would be greatly appreciated!

```
Incident Identifier: 3BCAF197-ABEF-40D8-A27E-ECDCEC448513
CrashReporter Key:   b7442fed2b23808a458077268ee149054b7dfada
Hardware Model:      iPod3,1
Process:         MyMoodTrack [52]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/5F858141-F6ED-45D6-970A-94C39EE1AD4E/MyMoodTrack.app/MyMoodTrack
Identifier:      MyMoodTrack
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

>Date/Time:       2010-08-03 16:53:53.720 -0400
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.0 (8A293)
Report Version:  104

>Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

>Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x33b621d0 0x33ae9000 + 496080
1   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x33b621c0 0x33ae9000 + 496064
2   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x33b621b2 0x33ae9000 + 496050
3   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x33b766fa 0x33ae9000 + 579322
4   libstdc++.6.dylib                 0x3015fa20 0x3011b000 + 281120
5   libobjc.A.dylib                   0x3433b9ec 0x34336000 + 23020
6   libstdc++.6.dylib                 0x3015ddf2 0x3011b000 + 273906
7   libstdc++.6.dylib                 0x3015de46 0x3011b000 + 273990
8   libstdc++.6.dylib                 0x3015df16 0x3011b000 + 274198
9   libobjc.A.dylib                   0x3433a8cc 0x34336000 + 18636
10  CoreFoundation                    0x328ebb72 0x328cc000 + 129906
11  MyMoodTrack                       0x000057e0 -[MyMoodTrackerAppDelegate performV160Upgrade] (MyMoodTrackerAppDelegate.m:251)
12  MyMoodTrack                       0x000061f6 -[MyMoodTrackerAppDelegate loadDataFile] (MyMoodTrackerAppDelegate.m:168)
13  MyMoodTrack                       0x0000444a -[MyMoodTrackerAppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:] (MyMoodTrackerAppDelegate.m:59)
14  UIKit                             0x305c6416 0x305b8000 + 58390
15  UIKit                             0x307087fc 0x305b8000 + 1378300
16  UIKit                             0x30615132 0x305b8000 + 381234
17  UIKit                             0x30614a56 0x305b8000 + 379478
18  UIKit                             0x30614500 0x305b8000 + 378112
19  GraphicsServices                  0x3323a140 0x33236000 + 16704
20  CoreFoundation                    0x3293daa4 0x328cc000 + 465572
21  CoreFoundation                    0x3293f848 0x328cc000 + 473160
22  CoreFoundation                    0x32940626 0x328cc000 + 476710
23  CoreFoundation                    0x328e98e4 0x328cc000 + 121060
24  CoreFoundation                    0x328e97ec 0x328cc000 + 120812
25  UIKit                             0x305be280 0x305b8000 + 25216
26  UIKit                             0x305bce10 0x305b8000 + 19984
27  MyMoodTrack                       0x0000258c main (main.m:14)
28  MyMoodTrack                       0x00002528 start + 44

>Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x33b16c4c 0x33ae9000 + 187468
1   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x33bbfe44 0x33ae9000 + 880196
2   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x33bbf894 0x33ae9000 + 878740
3   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x33bbfa34 0x33ae9000 + 879156
4   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x33b63d82 0x33ae9000 + 503170
5   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x33b5cfcc 0x33ae9000 + 475084

>Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x33b6485c 0x33ae9000 + 505948
1   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x33b63e98 0x33ae9000 + 503448
2   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x33b5cfcc 0x33ae9000 + 475084

>Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x33aea658 0x33ae9000 + 5720
1   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x33aec724 0x33ae9000 + 14116
2   CoreFoundation                    0x3293e2c8 0x328cc000 + 467656
3   CoreFoundation                    0x32940582 0x328cc000 + 476546
4   CoreFoundation                    0x328e98e4 0x328cc000 + 121060
5   CoreFoundation                    0x328e97ec 0x328cc000 + 120812
6   WebCore                           0x31912056 0x3190f000 + 12374
7   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x33b63986 0x33ae9000 + 502150
8   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x33b590e4 0x33ae9000 + 458980

>Thread 4:
0   MyMoodTrack                       0x00023bfc -[FlurryConnectionDelegate isDone] (FlurryConnectionDelegate.m:32)
1   MyMoodTrack                       0x000235c0 +[FlurryHTTPEater sendMethod:to:body:headerFields:timeoutInterval:useWebView:] (FlurryHTTPEater.m:72)
2   MyMoodTrack                       0x00022982 +[FlurrySession sendSessionsToServerWithTimeout:useWebView:requestAds:sendCurrentSession:] (FlurrySession.m:762)
3   MyMoodTrack                       0x0001fd7c +[FlurrySession sendSessionsToServerForAppCircle] (FlurrySession.m:739)
4   Foundation                        0x31ed2c96 0x31ec7000 + 48278
5   Foundation                        0x31f579da 0x31ec7000 + 592346
6   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x33b63986 0x33ae9000 + 502150
7   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x33b590e4 0x33ae9000 + 458980

>Thread 5:
0   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x33aea658 0x33ae9000 + 5720
1   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x33aec724 0x33ae9000 + 14116
2   CoreFoundation                    0x3293e2c8 0x328cc000 + 467656
3   CoreFoundation                    0x32940582 0x328cc000 + 476546
4   CoreFoundation                    0x328e98e4 0x328cc000 + 121060
5   CoreFoundation                    0x328e97ec 0x328cc000 + 120812
6   Foundation                        0x31f0271e 0x31ec7000 + 243486
7   Foundation                        0x31ed2c96 0x31ec7000 + 48278
8   Foundation                        0x31f579da 0x31ec7000 + 592346
9   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x33b63986 0x33ae9000 + 502150
10  libSystem.B.dylib                 0x33b590e4 0x33ae9000 + 458980

>Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x3e5bb24c
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x00153f6c      r6: 0x2fffe028      r7: 0x2fffe038
    r8: 0x3e327318    r9: 0x00000065     r10: 0x316c706c     r11: 0x3e32fd5c
    ip: 0x00000025    sp: 0x2fffe038      lr: 0x33b621c7      pc: 0x33b621d0
  cpsr: 0x000f0010

>Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0x41fff +MyMoodTrack armv7  <f37bad4a272c4f4d59e335707330aba3> /var/mobile/Applications/5F858141-F6ED-45D6-970A-94C39EE1AD4E/MyMoodTrack.app/MyMoodTrack
   0xf3000 -    0xf4fff  dns.so armv7  <240b8d3f07b4fcb234de598f8e67de1a> /usr/lib/info/dns.so
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe26fff  dyld armv7  <697ae459733a7f0b6c439b21ba62b110> /usr/lib/dyld
0x3000e000 - 0x30040fff  AddressBook armv7  <3dde743216bbf016019b59f821dda6e3> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x30044000 - 0x30106fff  CFNetwork armv7  <9fdd61632fd1b48d65daba561528946f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x30107000 - 0x3010cfff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <d33678689445fcf1898314262fd1ebd3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x30117000 - 0x3011afff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <85f01f53a7455a34fbdedc76bd692d74> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x3011b000 - 0x30165fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <baab09769f92decea73680bc15aa8618> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x30172000 - 0x3019bfff  IMFoundation armv7  <8e003a136638c28edc7b5333b8166b5a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/Frameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x301b2000 - 0x30250fff  Celestial armv7  <7a01b8d8cd2054d9b0d987bda6c52d9c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x30347000 - 0x30381fff  IOKit armv7  <5e0169de165c2fd25a2ddac1f3e19d06> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x30536000 - 0x3057bfff  IMCore armv7  <d5045ad82f9b89b1d4992f1f500724fa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/IMCore
0x30581000 - 0x305a0fff  Bom armv7  <c73b68b11b2801cefbfbdb6328a7fcfb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x305a1000 - 0x305b7fff  RawCamera armv7  <78168f60a21e67ce307c5ce30054dba6> /System/Library/CoreServices/RawCamera.bundle/RawCamera
0x305b8000 - 0x31762fff  UIKit armv7  <5bce9024bb5d8754f4477723c84cf3d1> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x31763000 - 0x3179cfff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <d38c937ae3548777da263d2657536189> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x318f3000 - 0x318f6fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <12f82e44ff36b29f8d0661878be83554> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x3190f000 - 0x31e60fff  WebCore armv7  <859bdd351085819fb4da07d12b41543f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x31e7a000 - 0x31eb4fff  IMAVCore armv7  <2bd608c3f68c2e9cd73212007eaf248d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMAVCore.framework/IMAVCore
0x31eb5000 - 0x31ec6fff  PersistentConnection armv7  <5e827d18f317b5ce7c61c91656ebc88e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x31ec7000 - 0x31fe6fff  Foundation armv7  <c985a61696030b4d1bdc8fe010f4e43b> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x31fe9000 - 0x32031fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <3b4a2849c10d100a178a3c2d9f6af523> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x32032000 - 0x32154fff  MediaToolbox armv7  <dea2c74c8c31430c58301edbe2b6eeb2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x3218f000 - 0x32238fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <1d74fa3a5cec309857503a51cb2df667> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x32311000 - 0x32312fff  DataMigration armv7  <2a90bcfdd519f8d7d3487151c77443ed> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x32313000 - 0x3231cfff  AccountSettings armv7  <cd5665c4a135694944eca0870d5350c5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x32328000 - 0x32366fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <cc8d6be7a5021266e26ebd05e9579852> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x323da000 - 0x32414fff  CoreMedia armv7  <6df383495d1acd2b036ad674a29d75c1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x32463000 - 0x32466fff  ActorKit armv7  <9858fda6756fb624164b7b83aefa6701> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
0x32467000 - 0x3246bfff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <942a91e5920a8798c1a1cf75f0750b2f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x32627000 - 0x32629fff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <c668de69901cce316252204135b4ce7f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x3262a000 - 0x326b9fff  AddressBookUI armv7  <7748fd02215f7d77eae9191cba201b97> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x326ba000 - 0x326c9fff  MobileDeviceLink armv7  <575a1afc08ed55608075204df14cc5f5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
0x326d9000 - 0x326e0fff  MobileWiFi armv7  <6d417a70ec3abd8258ed0fbab0994518> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x326e1000 - 0x32712fff  CoreLocation armv7  <722c5983f0589013d0243e2512d0dd1b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x32713000 - 0x32754fff  MessageUI armv7  <01029a352fe073ddf5103bad8274f1fe> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x32841000 - 0x32860fff  Conference armv7  <f38c0563d62880f21ee676529aeafa47> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Conference.framework/Conference
0x32861000 - 0x3286afff  CoreVideo armv7  <58180e899ec56cd8bca00221dea2bc32> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x3286b000 - 0x32874fff  ITSync armv7  <e00a78c04f8ae7515da25fdc09281f4f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ITSync.framework/ITSync
0x32876000 - 0x32895fff  MobileSync armv7  <be1b235840ae625d49f684c39ab083da> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
0x3289a000 - 0x328c8fff  MIME armv7  <a6dbab95d27cf0fe94c2251df2549e10> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x328cc000 - 0x3299efff  CoreFoundation armv7  <17c9c36ae8824496b507446869cd4d9d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x329c0000 - 0x329c3fff  ApplePushService armv7  <0477bf826cbba75183069e1e80879a99> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x32ad6000 - 0x32b75fff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <894df23ebbc4df713d9519141a61dd19> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x32b93000 - 0x32b9bfff  libkxld.dylib armv7  <4ec35c4d1e1e73416aea84537829ce91> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
0x32bbd000 - 0x32bfdfff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <94f3f69708e8f008b3f092430f46e4b6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x32c05000 - 0x32c12fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <27ad6b3a74ce1068586eabd6a553183f> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x32c13000 - 0x32c1cfff  WebBookmarks armv7  <3b3f590d3bd1fdf29a14769cbe8dc933> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x32c55000 - 0x32c97fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <bc8796c8e011fea9923170d3c948a694> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x32cae000 - 0x32cb4fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <df3c6cea5e6848109a6e033e1d883320> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x32cb5000 - 0x32d23fff  ProofReader armv7  <479bd40ac65cb7e6c3000d79d649571f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x32d24000 - 0x32d2ffff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <19a78978d5908bedc6496470fe542936> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x32dff000 - 0x32f23fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <802e4d5c449b69d9552809e5230baa84> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x32f24000 - 0x32f24fff  Accelerate armv7  <f4c04cdfdb64d209828315cdd5b60bf9> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x32f98000 - 0x32fa5fff  OpenGLES armv7  <e397de408a0a789f816bc1803ae58faf> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x32fa6000 - 0x32fb4fff  Notes armv7  <56a4dfe587cf5b965edbd6c390ccbf24> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
0x32ff7000 - 0x33026fff  VideoToolbox armv7  <4c4faee61a6e7d80d6d3a58194075642> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x33027000 - 0x33067fff  CoreAudio armv7  <1723726845b73efbeca75b33d75f335a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x33068000 - 0x330bbfff  EventKit armv7  <7f18bef514a44edeccc9619b10f4f1c2> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x330cf000 - 0x330e7fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <ccca76990c424fab4771b2fafd0dc623> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x33100000 - 0x331a8fff  QuartzCore armv7  <109b4f6a3d2ee5aa1bb5775ab5a489bc> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x331aa000 - 0x331acfff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <06dd6032c40b1feb094d63eeb2002d6d> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x331ad000 - 0x331affff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <1fdf9182a63464743901526caf39240a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x331df000 - 0x331e2fff  IOSurface armv7  <69e41f7996daba75c65b85a4800fd038> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x331fd000 - 0x33205fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <b8fc1381e87a55740d9ac66195039a63> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x33236000 - 0x33241fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <7194df9e594ae0fd9d9c600ccf456a08> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x33242000 - 0x3326cfff  DataAccess armv7  <45bf80615cbfaab4d2e29cb923723424> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x3326d000 - 0x33274fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <5d079712f5a39708647292bccbd4c4e0> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x33275000 - 0x332d8fff  AVFoundation armv7  <39ad1d85ae4627ed77de7751e8a3b4ec> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x33465000 - 0x3348efff  ContentIndex armv7  <40405e868ddfb485115719c167925b6b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x3348f000 - 0x334c2fff  iCalendar armv7  <a8def1c4ef73199eee71bc525005831b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
0x334c3000 - 0x334c4fff  CoreSurface armv7  <dc0eed99a5c683f3e4942e454b85d66f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x334ef000 - 0x3351dfff  AppSupport armv7  <2a64271b39599b2180d0dfd3141027ee> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x335c2000 - 0x335c2fff  vecLib armv7  <85f89752df7814c1b243c26f59388523> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x335c5000 - 0x335cafff  BluetoothManager armv7  <c3a48ff43d836b3025597f4ff5e5c858> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BluetoothManager.framework/BluetoothManager
0x336a1000 - 0x336cffff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <2b44ac2fc47fc45c4006d08019688dbb> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x337cd000 - 0x3385afff  ImageIO armv7  <abf07fc0430aaf2a2823753c78061aac> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x339b2000 - 0x339b3fff  Marco armv7  <89d4f32ac1cbb0b4f5066308fa5f422a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco
0x339b4000 - 0x339b6fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <74e2bd725da63513053b4fa41d8cd89c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x339b7000 - 0x33ad0fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <c4f4fd74dfa672fb4d84914585bbada5> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x33ae9000 - 0x33bf6fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <95600851b7aca75450d596a93c51d858> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x33c6f000 - 0x33c9dfff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <da59479c5e620202ed123e477163240d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x33ca7000 - 0x33cb3fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <7624f0a9e197261f2df43edb86ba0256> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x33cb7000 - 0x33cbafff  CertUI armv7  <fff763f01a1037dcd9ce6914e25068ca> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x33cd2000 - 0x33d1bfff  GMM armv7  <9c4efdff49ea9e6a17b5d44bcd98b6c1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
0x33ddd000 - 0x33df2fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <1ed920d5a995cd94e71c41631d7c551e> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x33df3000 - 0x33e1dfff  libtidy.A.dylib armv7  <25fba468c726d1a59aa109a5a76631f5> /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
0x33ed9000 - 0x33ee9fff  TelephonyUI armv7  <dd37e6ff7158a0d44c99efa6ad659dd1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TelephonyUI.framework/TelephonyUI
0x33eea000 - 0x33efafff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <a27ef7495f01196dd12f6382eb44a092> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x33f31000 - 0x341cbfff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <fbc3f7ad1260a159d75be53218fa9e0c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x34211000 - 0x34240fff  CoreText armv7  <76eb1b63d684c3d21dba9e8129666d2f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x3428f000 - 0x34335fff  WebKit armv7  <a1d04572b3214188f60f2d1961ac1fe8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x34336000 - 0x343d6fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <89553a61e05078fd178ac0ea2081ae40> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x345f1000 - 0x345f9fff  MobileBluetooth armv7  <0bd0c65f4350b5d81f81449fae029a04> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
0x345fa000 - 0x3460dfff  libmis.dylib armv7  <9fbf2930731e2da9863eacdff8b121a2> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x3460e000 - 0x34711fff  CoreData armv7  <0abaeddf54d093fa5cf680b0d644d8e9> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x3474a000 - 0x3482bfff  GameKitServices armv7  <5bfca52ad46cbf5f8ea3888f646f3511> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GameKitServices.framework/GameKitServices
0x34831000 - 0x348b8fff  Message armv7  <32383927596c6b8c0837a5cd4b2bc0d4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
0x34960000 - 0x34b9efff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <83f1b1c1956ed14bf6f6c7923ee9f2fc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x34f21000 - 0x34f65fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <36b9bc7d02e29c8d321dd0d7bf7e115e> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x34f66000 - 0x34fa5fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <b96f5e231a3e39677b5e3621d61d2f11> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x34fb9000 - 0x350a1fff  libGLProgrammability.dylib armv7  <9bcf5fe3e7abc344425e581ff2896579> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLProgrammability.dylib
0x350a2000 - 0x351c0fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <4022bbf12f11dd1f6b75662c764e7f7c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x351c6000 - 0x351f5fff  QuickLook armv7  <78442b5e66e7845f89afcc02b6982ef2> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x3522e000 - 0x35244fff  EAP8021X armv7  <4177ec92cd0e2a4a23c79fac68de5c2e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x352bd000 - 0x352f3fff  Security armv7  <7cea1027f1a381b8d6c5ffae4dae0d22> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
```

Comment: I would post a link to a properly formatted crashlog, as well as the code for the method where it crashed (and probably the class's header file).

Comment: Hi Ben - just wondering how I can better format the crashlog? I don't know much about symbolication, but I did drag into the Organizer window, and the app that was crashing was build & archived, so the dsym should have been there. I did get the 3 line numbers of lines 11-13 which weren't there before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im not sure what `entry.emotion` is, but i assume its an integer (since you are using it as an index, and subtracting one from it)? if so, you are probably causing an index out of bounds error by trying to access an index in your array that does not exist (-1 for instance)

Comment: You're supposed to use your magic crystal ball to tell you what it is and what value it has... duh.

Comment: You're correct, entry.emotion is an integer. Sometimes entry.emotion has a value of 0 (as a default), which means when I subtract 1, I'm out of range. Thanks! It's amazing how often the most obvious problems are not so obvious until you show them to someone else.